# Ansible-pull cofiguration-management for large-scale server farm

Tags: ansible

Here's the situation,

I've say 100 webservers, 100 DB-servers and 100 Backend-servers. All of them managed by Ansible. I want to use Ansible-pull to lighten the load on Ansible Admin node and expedite process.

The question is, when I run ansible-pull on each node with local mode, how I can apply specific role to that node. For example, how a webserver node will know that, it needs to apply webserver role to itself?

I hope I've made myself clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `'hostname'.yml` file so only the matching host will run that .yml file.

Example repo could contain:
db1.yml
db2.yml
db3.yml

Then a server with hostname 'db1' will only run the `db1.yml` playbook. So in that playbook you can call all the tasks and roles it should have.

From the man page:

> ansible-pull will look for a playbook based on the host’s
>              fully-qualified domain name, on the host hostname and finally a playbook named local.yml.